# How do you find the InlineModelAdmin from the admin context data?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to test that the correct form is used with an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)

I have set the custom form with:

```
class RateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Rate
    fk_name = 'project'
    extra = 1
    form = RateForm
```

However when I try to check that the `RateForm` is indeed being uses I get:

a generated modelform:

```
formsets = response.context['inline_admin_formsets']

ipdb> formsets[1].forms[0].__class__
<class 'django.forms.widgets.RateForm'>
```

But I wanted the form used to be:

```
<class 'billing.forms.RateForm'>
```

Is this form only used during validation and the generated RateForm widget in the context data?

Comment: Are you sure you need to test this? Django should test that it does the correct thing when you specify `form` for an inline class.

Comment: I agree. I am testing to ensure that I have set the form to use my custom form that has specific validation. ie. I am testing that I have set that `form` inline class correctly...Aha...I should just assert `RateInline.form == RateForm`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django takes your `form` and passes it to `modelform_factory` to generate the form class used in the admin (source code}. This allows model admin options like `fields` to be included in the form.

I don't think you should worry about the type of `formsets[1].forms[0]`. Treat that as an implementation detail. As you suggested in the comments, it should be enough to assert that `RateInline.form == RateForm`, and trust that Django does the correct thing when you set `form`.